# How to find Manhattan Distance in one-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

Say I have the following 5x5 one-dimensional array. (The white number refers to the index. Ignore the other colors, I'm working on an A* implementation and was using this image as a reference)

[image]

And I want to find the Manhattan distance between index 16 and index 9, which would be 5.

Normally Manhatten Distance is done like so:

`return Math.abs(a.x - b.x) + Math.abs(a.y - b.y)`

But with a one-dimensional array I don't have x (col) and y (row) values. I only have the index. Is the only way to calculate the Manhattan Distance with a 1D array to turn the indexes into x and y values and then calculate it normally like this?

```
let aX = Math.floor(idx1 % width);
let aY = Math.floor(idx1 / width);

let bX = Math.floor(idx2 % width);
let bY = Math.floor(idx2 / width);

return Math.abs(aX - bX) + Math.abs(aY - bY);
```

Or is there a way to do it without converting the one-dimensional indexes to two dimensions?

Comment: Sorry, posted an answer before I read you already knew that. The answer is basically no, the Manhattan distance will be a function of the width of your matrix. You need to know the horizontal and vertical displacement. (You don't need to take the floor of `%` however -- it's always an integer).

Comment: Ah, I was hoping there'd be a more efficient way. Alright, very well. Thanks!

Comment: As it depends on the dimensions of the matrix, you need a kinda conversion!